# Guice's AOP extension not working on super type

Tags: aop, guice, cglib

I have a following hierarchical structure:

```
public class ItemImpl extends RepositoryBase<ItemImpl> { 
   @Inject
   ItemImpl( dependency ) { 
      super( dependency )
   }
}

public class RepositoryBase<T> extends Base<T> {
   public RepositoryBase( dependency ) { //Constructor without @Inject
      super( dependency )
   }

   @Intercept <--- Works
   public someMethod( ) {}
}

public class Base<T> {
   public Base( dependency ){ } //Constructor without @Inject

   @Intercept <--- Does not work ***
   public someMethod( ) {}
}
```

As you can see above, Interception does not work at the level 3 of the hierarchy. According to Guice's AOP limitation, instance have to be created using Guice and child ItemImpl has constructor with @Inject so I guessed parents of this child should work.

Why doesn't interception at level 3 work and why does the interception at level 2 work? Both of the parents does not have constructor with @Inject?

Comment: How are you obtaining instances of `RepositoryBase<T>` and `Base<T>`? I don't understand how Guice is creating those instances since it requires either an `@Inject` annotated constructor or a zero argument constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Cglib creates a dynamic sub class that overrides an intercepted method where Guice applies its magic in this overriden method. This can only be done for the "top" method but not for "grand parent" methods. Therefore, only the method in `RepositoryBase` is intercepted while the method defined in `Base` is hidden from Guice.

Note that it is technically possible to create byte code that calls a grand parent method. Cglib does however not offer such capabilities.